# How to replace non-positive values of some columns of my dataframe with NA in r

Tags: r, for-loop, na

I have a dataframe, and I want to assign `NA` to non-positive values of specific columns.

I'll try to realize a minimal reproducible example with the `mtcars` dataframe where I'll try to change with `NA` the values of the two columns `cyl` and `disp` that are <= 5.

```
library(dplyr)

view(mtcars)


Nomi <- c("cyl", "disp")

for(i in Nomi) {
  mtcars$i[mtcars$i <= 5] <- NA
}
```

Nomi is the vector with the names of `mtcars` columns where I want to change values with `NA`.

I don't fully understand the error message I get, I'd like to find a solution that can make the changes in `NA`.

Comment: `$` won't work with characters. Use `mtcars[[i]]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with `dplyr`, you can use an `ifelse` statement in `mutate(across())`. It means `across` `cyl` and `disp` column, if the values in these two columns are `<= 5`, replace it with `NA`. Otherwise, keep the original value (`.x`).

Note that this will only output results to the console **WITHOUT** actually replacing the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% mutate(across(c(cyl, disp), ~ ifelse(.x <= 5, NA, .x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can directly do the replacement on the dataframe.

```
Nomi <- c("cyl", "disp")
df <- mtcars
df[Nomi][df[Nomi] <= 5] <- NA
df
```